# Why windows 10 has more than one "current version"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I see in [this Microsoft page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/release-information#windows-10-current-versions-by-servicing-option) that on 2022-01-25 Microsoft published new builds for three different versions of Windows 10: 20H2, 21H1 and 21H2.  Why?

Note that the title of the linked section is "Windows 10 current versions" (plural).  Can we say that 20H2 is "old"?  Instead of updating 20H2 to the latest build should Windows Update download the latest build of the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H* updates are feature releases. The "old" versions are also updated to include fixes, such as to resolve vulnerabilities. Enterprise deployments tend to hold onto H updates for longer periods, to check nothing is broken (compatibility with other software in the estate). But if there's a critical fix required for a Zero-Day attack, said clients will want that fix available in the version they're running across the estate.

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions of Windows, large updates that created a new stable build were called Service Packs. A Service Pack was a windows version that had a collection of all updates up to a certain point with certain updates not in it to create a more stable build than if you have a non-service pack build updated to the latest version.

In essence this creates a new version of that windows build with the aim to fix bugs and make it more stable.

Because not everyone installs the service pack at the same time, and these updates take a long time and are more impactful than normal updates, Microsoft decided that it does not want to make installing these service packs a mandatory install for newer updates.

So when you install a service pack or not, newer updates will be released for windows versions that contain the service pack or not.

In Windows XP for example, you have 3 service pack releases over the course of its lifespan. So an update was distributed 4 times, for each version, the base version and the 3 service pack versions.

Now, this question goes about Windows 10 with its releases named HyyHr, eg H21H2. These are in essense Service Pack releases.

Microsoft decided to create a service pack every half year to ensure that Windows 10 remains stable, as each service pack install basically cleans up the installation, keeping things snappy. Microsoft decided against supporting every build, so each build has an end-date, as indicated in your link.